# Conditional formatting based on cell value (for multiple columns)

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I would like to apply conditional formatting to a selection of data.

[image]

From cell "D2" (and beyond), cells should be shown in green if it is greater than or equal to cell C2 (and below).

Some examples:

- D2 shouldn't be green
- E2 should be green
- D9 should be green
- G9 shouldn't be green

How can I make this happen?

The google sheet can be found [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lqfRNFV9hRMYsA5azobRfQ8OJk7xG8UWhwOKUUsJZBE/edit?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this formula into the conditional formatting of `D2:G`

```
=$C2<=D2
```

To prevent cells `D2:G` from turning green if filled in when the cells in column C are still empty, use this one:

```
=AND($C2<=D2,$C2<>"")
```